# How to call assembly in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb

In gdb I can use `call` to run functions,but what if I want to run some additional assembly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prior to GCC 5 <sup>(1)</sup>, I don't know of a way to run arbitrary machine code unless you actually enter the machine code into memory and then run it.

If you want to run code that's *already* in memory, you can just set the instruction pointer to the start, a breakpoint at the end, then go. Then, after the breakpoint, change the instruction pointer back to its original value.

But I can't actually see the use case for this. That doesn't mean there *isn't* one, just that anything you can do by running code, you can also achieve by directly modifying the registers, flags, memory and so forth.

For example, the command:

```
info registers
```

will dump the current values of the registers while:

```
set $eax = 42
```

will change the `eax` register to `42`.

You can also change memory in this way:

```
set *((char*)0xb7ffeca0) = 4
```

This writes a single byte to memory location `0xb7ffeca0` and you can also use that same method to store wider data types.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> GCC 5 allows you to compile and execute arbitrary code with the `compile code` command, as documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compiling-and-Injecting-Code.html).

Comment: How to modify registers if `mov` etc can't be run directly?

Comment: @gdb: You can use `set $eax = 42`, for example. See the update.

Comment: Can you also demonstrate how to change memory with `set`?

Comment: There is a cases for executing a particular assembly instructions in a memory. It could be a multimedia commands, which result might be not easy to calculate. Or a few usual commands which easier to execute, than to edit a registers/memory by hand, with a probability to make an error.

Comment: It would be fun to make a Python API command that does it. Find some free executable memory, compile, write commands there, change ESP to it, set last command to jump back. Likely hard :-)

Comment: `compile code` was recently added to GDB and allows "arbitrary" compilation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31709579/895245

Answer (score 4):

**`compile code` command**

Introduced around 7.9, it allows code compilation and injection, documentation: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compiling-and-Injecting-Code.html

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -o main.out main.c
gdb main.out
```

Then in GDB:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x113d: file main.c, line 4.
Starting program: /home/ciro/test/main.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           int i = 0;
(gdb) next
5           printf("%d\n", i);
(gdb) compile code int j = 1; i = j; asm("nop");
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
1
[Inferior 1 (process 30256) exited normally]
```

Program output:

```
1
```

For this to work in GDB 7.9.1, GCC 5.1 I had to run GDB with:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(dirname "$(gcc -print-libgcc-file-name)"):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" gdb main.out
```

so that `libcc1.so` will be visible: that is a recent GCC component that exposes a C API to the `cc1` compiler, but this was not needed anymore on Ubuntu 19.04. This was still required for C++ however on a minimal:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

and:

```
compile code int j = 1; i = j; asm("nop");
```

There are a few constructs that did not work as I expected:

- `return`: [In the GDB compile code command, what language constructs behave exactly as if they were present in the original source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710921/in-the-gdb-compile-code-command-what-language-constructs-behave-exactly-as-if-t)
- includes such as:

  ```
  compile code printf('asdf\n')
  ```

  in Ubuntu 19.04.

  On main.c above, `printf` without include worked because we already included it in the source, but if I try it on an empty `main()` without the include it fails with:

  ```
  gdb command line:1:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
  gdb command line:1:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
  gdb command line:1:8: warning: character constant too long for its type
  gdb command line:1:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  gdb command line:1:8: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
  gdb command line:1:1: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  ```
- In C++ Ubuntu 19.04:

  ```
  compile code std::cout << "Hello world\n";
  ```

  failed with:

  ```
  *** WARNING *** there are active plugins, do not report this as a bug unless you can reproduce it without enabling any plugins.
  Event                            | Plugins
  PLUGIN_PRE_GENERICIZE            | libcp1plugin
  PLUGIN_GGC_MARKING               | libcp1plugin
  PLUGIN_PRAGMAS                   | libcp1plugin
  gdb command line:1:6: internal compiler error: in plugin_build_decl, at libcc1/libcp1plugin.cc:1059
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
  Compilation failed.
  ```

  See also: [How to compile C++ code in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343227/how-to-compile-c-code-in-gdb)

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually work for something like `asm volatile ("mov $abc, %eax")`, when the language is C.  After the `compile` command returns, `$rax` still has its original value.  GDB 7.10 doesn't support the `compile` command when the source language is asm, so this doesn't work even when debugging a function written in asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, I hadn't tried that out. `compile` is really quite limited. But there is potential.

Comment: Yeah it looks really handy for C/C++, but not for just experimenting with what instructions do with different inputs.  I guess you could use a C variable as an output operand, but then you need an instruction to use it.  At that point it's probably easier to just put instructions in a file, assemble/link it, and single-step that.  Thanks for pointing it out, even though it's not a good answer to *this* question. >.<

Comment: Your example with `std::cout` can be rewritten with `-raw` argument as `compile code -raw #include <iostream> ^Mvoid _gdb_expr() { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }` (replace `^M` here with Ctrl-V, Enter) This does work for me.

Comment: @Ruslan thanks for clarifying what `-raw` does! Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work on Ubuntu 19.04 :-( A  C++ hello world fails with `‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’`, and an empty `main` fails with `warning: Could not find symbol "_ZSt4cout" for compiled module "/tmp/gdbobj-dxRNbH/out1.o".` when I tried.

Comment: `‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’` means you've failed to `#include <iostream>` in your `compile` command. The linker error happens to me when the app hadn't included `<iostream>` by itself, this I'm not sure how to fix from within GDB. For reference, see the full working bash/gdb session [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/TWyZ6vtn).