# Can GDB change the assembly code of a running program?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, x86

I want to add some extra funcionality to /bin/ls.
So I started it on gdb and added a breakpoint at the beginning.

Now question is: how can I change the code of a running program in memory? I can see the assembly code, but I'm not able to modify. How can I do it?

On Windows I can easily do this with olldbg for example. How about on Linux?

(I know that doing this I will only change the code of the process in memory. So then I can dump memory to a file, and then I'll have my changes saved in a binary file).

Thank you.

Comment: Just dumping won't create a real executable for you. Executables contain quite a lot of administrative stuff and relocation tables etc. If you want to patch, then use a hex editor. But generally, it is not a good idea to modify machine code that way at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can write binary to memory directly but GDB doesn't have an assembler build in by default you can however do something like `set *(unsigned char*)0x80FFDDEE = 0x90` to change the mnemonic at that address to a NOP for example. You could however use NASM to write a shellcode and use perl or python to inject it into the program :)

You might also like this little .gdbinit file to make debugging allot easier: https://gist.github.com/985474

Comment: I really like your suggestion, but to inject a shellcode I would need a vulnerable buffer right? I'm not sure if /bin/ls would have a bug to exploit...

Comment: BTW this command `*(unsigned char*)` did not work. Are you sure about that?

Comment: No I mean with OllyDbg you can reassemble complete operations, if you want do do something like this with GDB you would need to assemble it with your assembler of choice and write it byte for byte into the memory with the trick I showed above.

Comment: Sorry forgot to place set in front, you would need to enter `set *(unsigned char*)0x80FFDDEE = 0x90` at the GDB prompt.

Comment: I had put together a blogpost a few years back that explains how one can alter code in memory both for Windows and Unix (gdb) similar to the answer above. http://www.technochakra.com/debugging-modifying-code-at-runtime/

Comment: Dude your .gdbinit is amazing. I am just starting with gdb and this helped a lot. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend a different approach: Download the [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package and modify the source code for `ls`. If possible, you should get the package from your distro's source repositories and apply any patches.

Answer (score 5):

**`compile code` command**

Introduced around 7.9, it allows code compilation and injection. Documentation: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compiling-and-Injecting-Code.html

I have given a minimal example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31709579/895245).

While it is not actual code modification, it does allow you to compile some code on the fly and run it once immediately, which might be enough.

And the [GNU cauldron presentation](http://people.redhat.com/pmuldoon/Cauldron_2014-jul.pdf) suggests that actual code modification may be added later on as an extension to this feature, see slide 30 "Fix and continue".

There are a few constructs that did not work as I expected like `return`, so I've asked why at: [In the GDB compile code command, what language constructs behave exactly as if they were present in the original source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710921/in-the-gdb-compile-code-command-what-language-constructs-behave-exactly-as-if-t)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gcc-plugin to write an extension to modify your coed and add any additional functionality in easy way during compilation process. if you work on machine level code, you should use binary instrumentation tools like Pin and Dyninst to instrument your binary file on the disk. however, if the overhead is important issue, you should work carefully with such tools.