# Linux ELF/LSB binary debugger

Tags: linux, debugging, reverse-engineering

I have a binary that I need to understand and modify the behaviour of, but I've never RE'd something on Linux before, just Windows. Can somebody recommend me a method/program to view this binary's ASM, trace through its execution as it's running, set breakpoints and also patch bytes (ideally while in its execution state)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can GDB change the assembly code of a running program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473908/can-gdb-change-the-assembly-code-of-a-running-program)

Answer (score 0):

command: objdump and readelf are the only things you need. Objdump can dump out the disassembly code with c/c++ source, readelf can make you understand the elf format, such as its layout, sections and debug format.