# What is the difference between dprintf vs break + commands + continue?

Tags: gdb

For example:

```
dprintf main,"hello\n"
run
```

Generates the same output as:

```
break main
commands
  silent
  printf "hello\n"
  continue
end
run
```

Is there a significant advantage to using `dprintf` over `commands`, e.g. it is considerably faster (if so why?), or has some different functionality?

I imagine that dprintf could be in theory faster as it could in theory compile and inject code with a mechanism [analogous to the `compile code` GDB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480868/how-to-call-assembly-in-gdb/31709579#31709579).

Or is it mostly a convenience command?

**Source**

In the 7.9.1 source, `breakpoint.c:dprintf_command`, which defines `dprintf`, calls `create_breakpoint` which is also what `break_command` calls, so they both seem to use the same underlying mechanism.

The main difference is that `dprintf` passes the `dprintf_breakpoint_ops` structure, which has different callbacks and gets initialized at `initialize_breakpoint_ops`.

`dprintf` stores list of command strings much like that of `commands` command, depending on the settings. They are:

- set at `update_dprintf_command_list`
- which gets called on after a `type == bp_dprintf` check inside `init_breakpoint_sal`
- which gets called by `create_breakpoint`.

When a breakpoint is reached:

- `bpstat_stop_status` gets called and invokes `b->ops->after_condition_true (bs);` for the breakpoint reached
- `after_condition_true` for `dprintf` is `dprintf_after_condition_true`
- `bpstat_do_actions_1` runs the commands

**Quick benchmark**

loop.c

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uintmax_t i, j, period, max;
    if (argc > 1) {
        max = strtoumax(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    } else {
        max = 10;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        period = strtoumax(argv[2], NULL, 10);
    } else {
        period = 1;
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (period != 0 && i % period == 0) {
            printf("%ju\n", j);
            j++;
        }
        i++; /* line 25 */
        if (i == max)
            break;
    }
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o loop.out loop.c
```

loop.gdb

```
b 25
commands
silent
printf "%d\n", i
c
end
```

Benchmark:

```
$ time gdb -n -q -batch -ex 'tb 39' -ex run -ex 'compile code printf("hello: %d\n", i)' -ex c -args ./loop.out 10000 0
```

So we see that both `dprintf` and `commands` slow things down massively, and that `dprintf` is only marginally faster than an equivalent `commands`.

I've asked if there's a way to use `compile code` to speed things up at: [GDB compile code and don't remove injected code after execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233877/gdb-compile-code-and-dont-remove-injected-code-after-execution)

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10, GDB 12.1.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main differences.

First, `dprintf` has some additional output modes that can be used to make it work in other ways.  See `help set dprintf-channel`, or the manual, for more information.  I think these modes are the reason that `dprintf` was added as a separate entity; though at the same time they are fairly specialized and unlikely to be of general interest.

More usefully, though, `dprintf` doesn't interfere with `next`.  If you write a breakpoint and use `commands`, and then `next` over such a breakpoint, gdb will forget about the `next` and act as if you had typed `continue`.  This is a longstanding oddity in the gdb scripting language.  `dprintf` doesn't suffer from this problem.  (If you need similar functionality from an ordinary breakpoint, you can do this from Python.)