# How to compile C++ code in GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm following this manual:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compiling-and-Injecting-Code.html

```
$ gdb ./test
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
(gdb) compile code std::cout << "Hello world\n";
No compiler support for language c++.
(gdb) compile code print("hello world")
No compiler support for language c++.
```

Does this mean that g++ is not supported? Or I need to configure GDB in some special way?

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, g++ 5.2, gdb 7.11

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essentials`

Comment: ArchLInux, g++ 8.2.0, gdb 8.2.1 also has the problem...

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely that the debugger you are using is too old.
It sounds too me that prior to 7.12 (maybe even later), user cannot redefine the `compile-gcc` symbol. As a result, there seems to be no way to specify a compiler for C++.. Nevertheless, the [issue](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18486) has been reported and addressed.
I guess the best solution is to update `gdb` to a newer version, by compiling it from the [official repository](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/tree/master/gdb).

Another solution would be to pre-compile the code manually and inject it manually within gdb, as explained [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33340/Code-Injection-into-Running-Linux-Application). Sounds fun but not sure this is the easy way!

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04 GDB 8.2.91, I can use simple compiles such as `compile code i = 1`, but when I tried to `compile code std::cout << "Hello world\n";
` it failed with: `internal compiler error: in plugin_build_decl, at libcc1/libcp1plugin.cc:1059`, minimal example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480868/how-to-call-assembly-in-gdb/31709579#31709579